# Request Context Deadline Exceeded

Tags: go, request

I am working on request contexts in Go. I am working on this endpoint for updating user accounts. When I send multiple incoming requests (POSTMAN) to the same endpoint consecutively, it returns the error `context deadline exceeded`. I am not sure why it only happens when I send the same request to the same endpoint continuously. The `context deadline exceeded` error appears around the 9th request and will appear 1 second later. After which, it blocks all requests to other endpoints as well.

**routes.go** [Every request will have a request Context - requestMiddleware]

```golang
func Routes(app repository.DatabaseRepo) http.Handler {

    r := chi.NewRouter()

    // Creates request context here with requestID
    r.Use(appMiddleware.RequestMiddleware)

    updateUserH := admin.New(app)
    r.Route("/admin", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Patch("/update-user", utils.MakeHTTPHandler(updateUserH.UpdateUser))
    })

    return r
}
```

**requestMiddleware.go** [Creates a context with requestID]

```golang
type RequestIDKey string
const RequestID RequestIDKey = "request_id"

func RequestMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        requestIDUuid := uuid.New().String()
        ctx := context.WithValue(req.Context(), RequestID, requestIDUuid)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, req.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}
```

**UpdateUser.go** [Uses the request context and sets a timeout]

```golang
func (app application) UpdateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) error {

    ....

    ctx := req.Context()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    utilsApp := utils.Application{DB: app.DB}
    err := utils.InjectUG(utilsApp, ctx, w.Header().Get("username"), "Admin")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return utils.WriteJSON(w, http.StatusOK, utils.ApiSuccess{Success: "[Admin] Successfully updated '" + updateUser.Username + "' user!", Status: http.StatusOK})

}
```

**UPDATE**
**`utils.InjectUG` function** is calling this database query. This query is causing the entire context to exceed the deadline upon firing multiple incoming requests. When I commented out `utils.InjectUG`, it works perfectly. I need this database query to check if a user belongs to a user group to access particular resources.

```golang
type Application struct {
    DB repository.DatabaseRepo
}

func InjectUG(app Application, ctx context.Context, username string, userGroups ...string) error {
    return app.CheckUserGroup(ctx, username, userGroups...)
}

// Determines if a user has been assigned that usergroup
func (app Application) CheckUserGroup(ctx context.Context, username string, userGroups ...string) error {

    isAuthorizedUser, err := app.DB.GetUserGroupsByUsername(ctx, username, userGroups...)
    if err != nil {
        return ApiError{Err: "Internal Server Error", Status: http.StatusInternalServerError}
    }
    if isAuthorizedUser {
        return nil
    }

    return ApiError{Err: "Access Denied: User does not have permission to access this resource", Status: http.StatusForbidden}
}
```

```golang
var SQL_GET_USERGROUPS_BY_USERNAME = `SELECT ug.user_group FROM user_groups ug
    LEFT JOIN user_group_mapping ugm 
    ON ugm.user_group_id = ug.user_group_id 
    WHERE ugm.user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = $1);`

func (m *PostgresDBRepo) GetUserGroupsByUsername(ctx context.Context, username string, userGroups ...string) (bool, error) {
    // IT FAILS ON THIS QUERY: context deadline exceeded
    rows, err := m.DB.Query(ctx, SQL_GET_USERGROUPS_BY_USERNAME, username)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Query failed at GetUserGroupsByUsername:", err)
        return false, err
    }

    var userGroup string
    if rows != nil {
        for rows.Next() {
            if err = rows.Scan(&userGroup); err != nil {
                return false, err
            }

            if utils.Contains(userGroups, userGroup) {
                return true, nil
            }
        }
    }
    return true, nil
}
```

Comment: not sure why you get deadline exceed. though note that your timeout is only valid for the `utils.InjectUG`.

Comment: It only happens when I send multiple requests to the same endpoint then postman just loads until the deadline is exceeded. Yes for utils.InjectUG, I am actually performing a SELECT query inside to my database which requires a context, could that be the issue?

Comment: Will `utils.InjectUG` lock something globaly? I guess that is why make the context of later request timeout.

Comment: You guys are right. I found out that it is because of the database query function that the `utils.InjectUG` function is calling. However, I am unsure why it is causing the issue. When I commented out the `utils.InjecUG` function, it works perfectly. The database query function it is calling checks if the user belongs in the particular user group for authorization purposes. I have updated the post with the database query it is calling, please help to see!

Comment: I have left a comment in the `GetUserGroupsByUsername` function where the `context deadline exceeded` issue is occurring in the edited post.

Comment: Is the query taking too long? Remove the context timeout and try measuring the time it takes to run the query and load its results. You may be dealing with a very slow query, or a very large result set.

Comment: The query runs fine, it is only returning 1 row with 1 column

Comment: If it only returns 1 row then `rows` will be closed implicitly after `rows.Next()`. But when it returns more than 1 row, and the `for` loop does not loop all the way through the rows, you should close it explicitly. Otherwise, the connections can not be used again, and subsequent calls will be blocked because there are not enough connections to use. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's weird that I can not find a duplicate question]

The `rows` should be closed explicitly.

The fix is to add `defer rows.Close()` after the error check:

```
  rows, err := m.DB.Query(ctx, SQL_GET_USERGROUPS_BY_USERNAME, username)
  if err != nil {
    log.Println("Query failed at GetUserGroupsByUsername:", err)
    return false, err
  }
+ defer rows.Close()
```

References:

- [Querying for multiple rows](https://go.dev/doc/database/querying#multiple_rows)

  > Looping all the way through the rows also closes it implicitly, but it is better to use defer to make sure rows is closed no matter what.
- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5#Conn.Query

  > The returned Rows must be closed before the connection can be used again.

Here is a simple demo that reproduces the issue:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgxpool"
    "golang.org/x/exp/slices"
)

func GetUserGroupsByUsername(ctx context.Context, db *pgxpool.Pool, userGroups ...string) (bool, error) {
    rows, err := db.Query(ctx, "values ('g1'),('g2')")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Query failed at GetUserGroupsByUsername:", err)
        return false, err
    }

    // uncomment the next line to address the issue.
    // defer rows.Close()

    var userGroup string
    for rows.Next() {
        if err = rows.Scan(&userGroup); err != nil {
            return false, err
        }

        if slices.Contains(userGroups, userGroup) {
            return true, nil
        }
    }
    log.Println("error:", rows.Err())
    return true, nil
}

func main() {
    connString := "postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname"
    pool, err := pgxpool.New(context.Background(), connString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to connect to database: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer pool.Close()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        log.Println(GetUserGroupsByUsername(ctx, pool, "g1"))
    }
}
```

The output:

```
2023/05/08 09:10:33 true <nil>
2023/05/08 09:10:33 true <nil>
2023/05/08 09:10:33 true <nil>
2023/05/08 09:10:33 true <nil>
2023/05/08 09:10:33 true <nil>
2023/05/08 09:10:33 true <nil>
2023/05/08 09:10:33 true <nil>
2023/05/08 09:10:33 true <nil>
2023/05/08 09:10:34 Query failed at GetUserGroupsByUsername: context deadline exceeded
2023/05/08 09:10:34 false context deadline exceeded
2023/05/08 09:10:34 Query failed at GetUserGroupsByUsername: context deadline exceeded
2023/05/08 09:10:34 false context deadline exceeded
^Csignal: interrupt
```

Comment: This solved my problem! This was a careless mistake on my end. I guess these are the perks of using context in Golang, it is difficult to detect the error with context.

Comment: @Zeke Lu, could you have a look at my question here as well. It may be similar although mine deals with the http client. I would really appreciate your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78191012/golang-grpc-server-making-http-requests-results-in-eof-and-context-deadline-exce